# retrieving the twitter search feeds dynamically using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Long back I used JSON and was successful to get the hash tag feeds from twitter and facebook. But presently I am just able to get the feeds but its not being updated constantly that means it not been update dynamically. I guess I need to ajaxify it, but I am not able to do that since I am not aware of ajax. Here is the code which I have used to get the twitter search feeds.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
   {    
   $("#Enter").click(function(event){ 
var searchTerm = $("#search").val()  ; 

var baseUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23";
$.getJSON(baseUrl + searchTerm + "&rpp=1500&callback=?", function(data) 
{
$("#tweets").empty(); 
if(data.results.length < 1) 
  $('#tweets').html("No results JOINEVENTUS"); 
$.each(data.results, function()
{
$('<div align="justify"></div>')
.hide()
.append('<hr> <img src="' + this.profile_image_url + '" width="40px" /> ')
.append('<span><a href="http://www.twitter.com/'
+ this.from_user + '">' + this.from_user 
+ '</a> ' + makeLink(this.text) + '</span>')
.appendTo('#tweets') 
.fadeIn(800); 
});
});
});
});

function makeLink(text) 
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;   
return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly to make it easier for us to help you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should help you. What I've done is moved the code which fetches the tweets into a function. This function is then called every X seconds to update the box. When the user enters a new search term and clicks "Enter", it will reset the timer.

```
var fetchSeconds = 30; //Number of seconds between each update
var timeout; //The variable which holds the timeout
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#Enter").click(function(event){ 
        //Clear old timeout
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        //Fetch initial tweets
        fetchTweets();
    });
});

function fetchTweets() {
    //Setup to fetch every X seconds
    timeout = setTimeout('fetchTweets()',(fetchSeconds * 1000));
    var searchTerm = $("#search").val(); 
    var baseUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23";
    $.getJSON(baseUrl + searchTerm + "&rpp=1500&callback=?", function(data) {
        $("#tweets").empty(); 
        if (data.results.length < 1) {
            $('#tweets').html("No results JOINEVENTUS"); 
        }
        $.each(data.results, function() {
            $('<div align="justify"></div>').hide()
                                            .append('<hr> <img src="' + this.profile_image_url + '" width="40px" /> ')
                                            .append('<span><a href="http://www.twitter.com/'+ this.from_user + '">' + this.from_user + '</a> ' + makeLink(this.text) + '</span>')
                                            .appendTo('#tweets')
                                            .fadeIn(800); 
        });
    });
}

function makeLink(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;   
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've edited the code as I mis-understood the question, but hopefully this is what you're after

Comment: thanks a lot fin1te for the help actually the tweets are not updating dynamically, what I am trying to do is exactly what twitter widget does on wordpress or other blogs which reflects the tweets with in no time.I am still figuring out how to do it.

Comment: I wanna do exactly what twitter is doing, tweets are retrieved dynamically `http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search`